# Why is order retrieval from JPA repository is changed when you save entity with its id?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I use JPA Repository with Hibernate as data source in a spring boot application.

My data before:

> [{"id":1,"name":"Not Stack"},{"id":2,"name":"Overflow"}]

I do a save operation with this data:

> {"id":1,"name":"Stack"}

Then when I do findAll() it retrieved:

> [{"id":2,"name":"Overflow"}, {"id":1,"name":"Stack"},]

Is this how it supposed to work? Any idea or workaround about this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`findAll()` returns the data in an unordered manner. The way it sorts these records is up to the RDBMS, and is usually the most convenient way. Relying on the order in this case is not a good idea.

To guarantee that the records are sorted by ID you can create your own method in your repository, for example:

```java
// Full query
@Query("SELECT t FROM Type t ORDER BY t.id")
List<T> findAllOrdered();

// Shorthand relying on method naming
List<T> findAllOrderById();
```

More information about the method naming can be found at [4.3.2 Query creation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) in the Spring Data JPA reference.

Or you can use the [`findAll(org.springframework.data.domain.Sort)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#findAll-org.springframework.data.domain.Sort-) method, for example:

```java
repository.findAll(Sort.by("id"));
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! I just noticed that my data order in DB is changed as if it created a new instance after deleting the old one. Is there a way to maintain order in DB when I do an update? Because from what I know, there's only one method save in JPA, right?

Comment: What do you mean with data order? What query did you execute to verify the data order in your database? Besides that, your solution lies in sorting your data by using an `ORDER BY` query, not by saving them in a specific order, because like I said, the default ordering is up to the database. The order in which you retrieve the results is up to you, by using `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Oh right, it was a mistake on my part. I did a simple query select from table. But I just tried to update manually and it resulted in the same behavior.

Comment: Like I said... it's up to the database to decide that. There might be a good reason to return objects by their last modification date or any other way. If you want your results sorted, then tell the database to do that by using `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Using java.util.List for maintaining relationships with entities does not preserve ordering when data is read from the database. This is natural, as database stores relationships and has no inherent concept of ordering. You must explicitly request ordering by ORDER BY in JPQL (or using findAllOrderById() method in repository). Or you may override findAll() method in repository to redirect to super.findAllOrderById() - in case your repository is an abstract class and not an interface.

Answer (score 2):

findAll() just gets all data, there is no specification of the order. You should use `findAllOrderById()` if you want the results ordered.